# One layout as background of other layout

Tags: android, layout

I want to set My Loading layout in the front of **mainview** layout and make it transparent. 
I made it like this:

[image: mainView]

[image: loadingView]

So, the question is: How to make mainView disabled (not clickable) While **loadingView** is visible.....?

Comment: create a progress dialog and set cancelable = false

Comment: android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" add this to your loadingView root element

Comment: @LucaNicoletti it doesn't help, mainView still clickable

Comment: How do you place the loadingView? post the code of where you inflate the 2 views please

Answer (score 0):

```
    ProgressDialog ProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    ProgressDialog.setMessage("");

    ProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
    ProgressDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the mainview's corresponding layout not to be clickable, by using the setClickable() method.
Set it back to true when loading ends.
It would be useful if you post some code.

Also, take a look to this [Android Layout make all children's not clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107263/android-layout-make-all-childrens-not-clickable)

it's about the layout's children, but i believe it is also helpful

Answer (score 0):

If your `loadingView` is covering the `mainView`, you can either make it (loadingView) clickable or add a `onClickListener` to it.

Now the clicks won't be taken by the `mainView` and its children.

In terms of code, you can either write:

```
loadingView.setClickable(true);
```

Or set click listener like:

```
loadingView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // do something here if you want
    }
});
```